# Trying to generate primes from 1 - n, but consistently is missing primes 3 and 5.?

Tags: python-3.x, primes

```
def generate_primes(n):
    """generate_primes(n) -> list
    Returns a list of all primes <= n."""
    from math import sqrt
    primes = [2]
    potentialPrimes = []
    for x in range(3, n + 1):
        potentialPrimes.append(x)
        if x % 2 == 0:
            potentialPrimes.remove(x)
    currentPrime = potentialPrimes[0]
    primes.append(currentPrime)
    while currentPrime < sqrt(n):
        for x in potentialPrimes:
            if x % currentPrime == 0:
                potentialPrimes.remove(x)
        currentPrime = potentialPrimes[0]
    for x in potentialPrimes:
        primes.append(x)
    print(primes)

generate_primes(100)
```

When I try to call the function, it prints this:

```
[2, 3, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

Any idea why?
And any ways to improve my code would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: This code is a very strange blend between naive prime calculation and Eratosthenes Sieve.  You need to make up your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In while loop you set currentPrime =5 but dont remove it from potential primes, so in next iteration potentialPrimes[0] is still 5. And 5%5==0 so it removes it from potential primes and does the same with 7.

Here's code in the same style, but correctly showing all of the numbers

```
def generate_primes(n):
  from math import sqrt
  primes=[]
  potentialPrimes=range(2,n+1)
  prime=potentialPrimes[0]
  while prime<sqrt(n):
      primes.append(prime)
      potentialPrimes.remove(prime)
      for potential in potentialPrimes:
          if potential%prime==0:
              potentialPrimes.remove(potential)
      prime=potentialPrimes[0]

  for potential in potentialPrimes:
      primes.append(potential)
  for number in primes:
      print number
```

Comment: So if I just move primes.append(currentPrime) into the first line of the while loop, it'll be fine?

Comment: nope, you still have some value in 2 places. that's 1. 2nd you should never iterate over a list and both modify the same list in loop body. (iterate over a copy of list). 3-why dont you use some well known method for finding primes? There are very efficient and simple algorithms for this already, done by guys much smarter than me, probably you and most of humanity.

Comment: 1. Little confused on what you mean by "some value in 2 places" 2. I don't know what you mean by ïterate over a list and both modfy the same ist in loop body." As you can see, I don't know much about this stuff. and 3. If I just used a well known method, I wouldn't be learning much.

Answer (score 0):

Removing items from a list as you iterate it is never a good idea

```
    for x in potentialPrimes:
        if x % currentPrime == 0:
            potentialPrimes.remove(x)
```